# ruby script that will call a command line command like ls -l, then take a specific column to feed to another fn

Tags: ruby

I want create a ruby script that I can run on the command line that will:

```
1. run a command line command like e.g.  "ls -l"
2. then I pass an argument for a specific column from the output of #1
3. for each column specified in #2, it will run another command
```

ls -l was just an example, I want this to be generic.

I'm newish to ruby, still not getting some of this so if you could commend what and how you did it that would be very helpful for me.

Comment: Your problem description is a bit unclear to me. Could you post an example invocation and the intended output for your script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I frequently use `|awk '{print $5;}'` (replace `5` with the one-indexed column of your choice) in pipelines. You can get similarly easy one-liners with `ruby` if you use some funny command-line switches. Compare:

```
$ ls -l | awk '{print $5;}'

404
16
10
8733
```

vs

```
$ ls -l | ruby -ne "a = split; puts a[4];"
nil
404
16
10
8733
```

`ruby -n` places an implicit `while gets() do .. end` loop around your code, and `ruby -e` passes script elements on the command line. Combine the two and you get some easy one-liner scripting ability, similar to `perl -ne` or `awk(1)`.

The manpage mentions another option that looks very useful:

```
 -a             Turns on auto-split mode when used with -n or
                -p.  In auto-split mode, Ruby executes
                      $F = $_.split
                at beginning of each loop.
```

Juan points out how to use it (single quotes prevents my shell, `bash(1)`, from interpreting the `$F[3]` as a variable reference).:

```
$ ls -l | ruby -ane 'puts $F[3]'
nil
root
root
root
root
sarnold
sarnold
...
```

Comment: The correct for your last command is `ls -l | ruby -ane 'puts $F[3]'`. BTW, your reply has been very useful for me. Thanks :)